# Uma propriedade do display:flex está bugando minha imagem

Tags: html, css

O problema esta no align-items: flex-end.

Depois que eu adicionei essa linha, junto com o display: flex. Minha imagem aumenta uns 4px em baixo quando eu passo o mouse em cima. E eu n sei pq isso acontece, preciso resolver isso.

Eu adicionei essas duas linhas porque eu quero colocar um texto dentro da imagem, se tem outra forma de fazer isso eu n sei. Eu vi isso aqui no stackoverflow, em outra pergunta.

CSS:

```
.img-container{
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-end;  
}

.img-container img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s ease;
    transition: transform .5s ease;
}

.img-container:hover img{
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
.texto{
    position: absolute;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.img-container h4{
position: absolute;
width: 600px;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>sas</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sis.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="img-container">

    <a href="#"><img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="lobo.html"></a>

    <h4><a href="#" class="texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto">Texto</a></h4>

   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Nesse código ai que coloquei para ilustrar meu problema, eu n sei pq o texto n esta dentro da imagem, mas tudo bem, no meu código aqui ele esta na imagem certinho. O problema é a imagem que aumenta o tamanho em baixo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vê se resolve o problema:

```css
#img-container{
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
#imagem{
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}
#imagem img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s ease;
    transition: transform .5s ease;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
#imagem:hover img{
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
#texto{
    position: absolute;
}
#texto a{
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>sas</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sis.css">
   <style type="text/css">
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="img-container">
      <div id="imagem">
         <a href="#"><img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="lobo.html"></a>
      </div>
      <div id="texto">
         <a href="#" class="texto">Digite aqui o texto que você deseja</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: N deu certo, com o seu código a imagem agora ta aumentando em cima tambem. E o texto deveria fica em baixo no lado inferior esquerdo. Mas vlw a tentativa.

Comment: Você pode explicar essa parte de aumentar em cima?

Comment: Em baixo do seu comentario tem um botão que executa o seu script. Ta vendo ali? Que alem de aumentar o tamanho da foto em baixo também aumenta em cima. Se vc n esta vendo ai, sera que n é culpa do navegador entao?

Comment: me desculpe, mas não entendi, então você quer tirar essa animação de aumentar a foto?

Comment: Eu coloquei um código na imagem para quando eu passasse o mouse em cima ela desse um zoom certo?! Ate ai tudo bem, só que eu tambem precisei colocar um texto em cima da foto, sendo assim eu usei as propriedades do display: flex. E uma delas a align-items: flex-end, fez com que a imagem desse uma "bugada", a imagem aumenta o tamanho dela em cerca de 4px no bottom. E no seu código a imagem aumenta n so no bottom como tambem no top.

Comment: Talvez seja melhor eu tirar esse display: flex. E arranjar outra forma de colocar o texto na imagem, vc conhece outro metodo? No meu caso eu n posso simplesmente ajustar no texto na imagem com o margin pq eu tenho mais de uma imagem e com textos de tamanhos diferentes.

Comment: editei o código, vê se é a resolução do problema, determinei um tamanho para a div da imagem, não deixando "bugado" a transição

Comment: Resolveu, muito obrigado pela ajuda colega!